# A Hard Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, problem-solving, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given that $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers such that $2x+4y+7z=2xyz$, find the minimum of $L=x+y+z$.

Does anybody have a solution that is purely algebraic?
I was only able to solve it with Lagrange multipliers.

Also, how would you show that the solution given by Lagrange multipliers is in fact a global solution?

Note: By a change of variables, this is equivalent to minimizing $$L=a+b+c-\frac{3}{2}$$ subject to $$2 a b c = a + 4 b + 2 a b + 7 c + a c - 9$$
where $a>0,b>\frac{1}{2},c>1$.

$L$ is minimized when $a=b=c=3$ and $L=7.5$.

Source: https://brilliant.org/problems/another-weird-inequality/
(I did not write this question)

Comment: I found the minimum of $L=x+y+z$ subject to $2x+4y+7z=2xyz$ without Lagrange multipliers, but simply setting partial derivatives to zero. For  $x=3;\;y=5/2;\;z=2$ I got $L=15/2$. I am curious to see how did you find the minimum without calculus. BTW you can answer yourself to let the community know how did you do...

Comment: Sorry, am asking because I was not able to do it without calculus ...

Comment: How did you find the minimum $L=7.5$  for $a=b=c=3$?

Answer (score 0):

For $x=3$, $y=2.5$ and $z=2$ we get the value $7.5$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, let $x=3a$, $y=2.5b$ and $z=2c$.

Thus, the condition gives 
$$3a+5b+7c=15abc$$ and we need to prove that
$$6a+5b+4c\geq15$$ or
$$(6a+5b+4c)^2(3a+5b+7c)\geq15^3abc,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$(6a+5b+4c)^2(3a+5b+7c)\geq\left(15\sqrt[15]{a^6b^5c^4}\right)^2\cdot15\sqrt[15]{a^3b^5c^7}=15^3abc.$$
Done!

Comment: How did you find $x,y,z$ which give the minimum without calculus?

Comment: @Raffaele I saw your result! :) :) :). I used the Lagrange multipliers method, of course, but since I don't like this method, I found the way, which you saw.

Answer (score 0):

Express $x$: $$x =
{4y+7z\over 2(yz-1)}$$ We get rational function in $y$ with parameter $z$: $$ L = {2y^2z+2yz^2+2y+5z\over
2(yz-1)}$$
We are searching for local minimum $m$ of $L$ (which is greater then it local maximum). So the equation $L=m$ must have exactly one solution (at fixed $z$) on $y$ thus the discriminat $D_y$ of:
$$ 2y^2z+2y(z^2-mz+1)+5z+2m=0$$
must be $0$, so (I skip some calculation here) 
$$m^2z^2-2mz(z^2+3)+(z^4-8z^2+1)=0$$
If we expres $m$ we get (we choose positive sign (obviously?)):
$$m = {z^2+3+ \sqrt{(14z^2+8)}\over z}$$
Here I could not skip the derivate (actually I could, but it is bothersome). If you calculate it you see we get $z=2$ ... and $L ={15\over 2}$.